# API Audience Endpoint doesn't return all audience

Tags: javascript, angular, api, typescript

Has anyone run into the issue where **not all data returned from server**? At the moment there are missing couple of audience/data which are returned in the following endpoint: http://dev.com/audience/table-data

That mean in the returned list of audience from server missing some audience.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the API page results? Very often, even if you don't request to limit results, the server will page in order to make the response feasible. In these cases, there is normally either an HTTP header containing the "next page" or data in the response to indicate there are more results.

Comment: @Fenton tnx for reply. Yes it is.
Ok if the case is same as you describe. 
What you suggest? 
How I can modified the req/header to get all data?

Comment: Some APIs won't go above a certain size - so you have to loop and request the next page until you have all the data. Some APIs limit by a maximum number of results, others target a size of data when serialized to JSON. This is especially the case for performance APIs (such as Azure Search Index).

Comment: @Fenton Ok, I will try. Thank you very much for helping!